# How to change size of resource icon in button using FancyButtons library?

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there is a way to change size of resource icon in button created with FancyButtons library https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons ?

In the documentation I see only how to change size of font icon.

My icon is raster png, so I can`t convert it to svg and font icon properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: better ask at github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons/issues/46).
It can be done programmatically:

```
mFbWeiXinLogin.setIconResource(R.drawable.umeng_socialize_wechat);
    mFbWeiXinLogin.setIconPosition(FancyButton.POSITION_LEFT);
    mFbWeiXinLogin.getIconImageObject().setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

put Icon in the drawable folder and then use like this :

```
fancy:fb_iconResource="@drawable/instagram"
```

visit this for more detail https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons/tree/master/samples

In this project you got the idea to perform this.